# How to change the expanded height in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface

I am new to flutter learning a flutter UI build from youtube. While I am using the expanded widget, I found the output is not what I want, just wanna ask is there any way to limit the height of the expanded widget.
[This is my current UI looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muk7X.png)

```
SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: 52,
                width: 52,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFF2BEA1),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: SvgPicture.asset("icons/icons/menu.svg"),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "\t\tMake Cents out of \n\t\tSolar",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  fontSize: 38,
                  color: Colors.blueGrey[900]),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29.5),
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Search",
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset("icons/icons/search.svg"),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: .85,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CategoryCard(
                    title: "Promotion of the day",
                    svgSrc: "icons/icons/Hamburger.svg",
                    press: () {},
                  ),
                  CategoryCard(
                    title: "Promotion of the day",
                    svgSrc: "icons/icons/Hamburger.svg",
                    press: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0, 0, 0),
              child: Text(
                "Solar Panel",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ],
```

I wanna know is there any way to control the height of the expanded widget so that my container with text can connect right below the custom Category Card. Or should I use another widget instead of using the expanded widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the `Expanded` widget will fill up all the remaining screen space. If you instead want to use a set size, you can use a `Container` or `SizedBox` with their width and height parameters.

To get a better understanding of constraints in general, I suggest you check out [this flutter documentation page all about constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints).

Comment: Thanks a lot. ConstrainedBox solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

To set a minimum and maximum size (width and height) for a widget you can use `ConstrainedBox` widget, learn more about it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html)

Comment: Thanks, ConstrainedBox solved my problem.

Comment: @RogerWong Happy to help, could you please mark it as the accepted answer then?

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the height of the `Expanded` widget. It takes all the space that is available on the screen. I suggest you to use `SizedBox` and explicitly provide the required height and set width as `double.infinity`.

Comment: Alright, just realized that Expanded will take full space. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I suggest `ConstrainedBox` widget to set minimum and maximum heights.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31473041)